# How I can insert birth date in MySQL with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a birth date in MySQL with php, but it displays `00-00-0000`,
In html I have three dropdowns with Month, Date and Year, and in MySQL the column is `name: birthdate`, `Type: DATE`. I'm trying to insert with the below PHP script, but I can not.

Please see the script below:

```
if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['last']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['first']) && !empty($_POST['last']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $user = new User();
    $user - > id['id'];
    $user - > firstname = $_POST['first'];
    $user - > lastname = $_POST['last'];
    $user - > email = $_POST['email'];
    $user - > password = $_POST['password'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $dt = $_POST['dt'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $user - > birthdate = $date_value = "$month/$dt/$year";
    if ($user - > Create()) {
      header("Location:profile.php");
    } else {
      echo "<a>User already exist!</a>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the dropdown form?

Comment: And also share  database detail  for birth-date column which date type you have set becasue you need to convert in proper format.

Comment: Just change to `$user->birthdate = $year."-".$month."-".$day`. it means remove the `"` and make the correct date format.

Comment: You can store it in $year."-".$month."-".$day this format

Comment: Default mysql date format is YYYY-MM-DD, pass ur date in this format

Comment: you need to make it clear what the contents of $_POST is for : 'year', 'month' & 'dt' because otherwise people are just guessing here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your birthdate like below

```
 $month = date('m', strtotime($month));
   /* or you can directly covert like this also $month = date('m', strtotime($_POST['month'])); */
    $date_value = $year. "-" .$month . "-".$dt;
    $user->birthdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_value));
```

Here i have convert your date in Y-m-d format as MySQL date datatype accept this format  [You can find more about strtotime on this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Gents, now is displaying "1970-01-01" Please see the html code

Comment: @k-wayne i have change my code as per your html your month value is month name so first we need to convert in to numeric format using strtotime function. please check now

Comment: feel happy to help you :-)

Comment: Dinesh, I just saw that the month always remains the same, its not changing 1988-01-08......"01"

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you use `.` to concatenate strings, try:

```
$Date = $year . "/" . $month.  "/" . $dt;

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$Date);
```

Your code should be

```
$user -> birthdate = $newformat;
```

Comment: your'e missing a concatenation after $month: $Date = $year . "/" . $month  . "/" . $dt;

Comment: <select id="date" name="dt">
                            <option value="1">01</option>
                        </select>
                        <select id="month" name="month">
                            <option value="1">Jan</option>
                        </select>
                        <select id="year" name="year">
                            <option value="2003">2003</option>  
                        </select>